# How do I generate a random vector (0,1) with a known probability in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, probability

I am using the following code

```
operation=[rand(1,noOfNodes)>prob];
```

to generate 1 and zeros (`noOfNodes` times). If I use `prob=0.2` and try 100 values there exist in some cases 40 zeros. Isn't it weird?

I need the probability of getting zeros less than 0.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's not weird. That's probability for ya.

If you flip a coin 100 times, you don't always get 50 heads and 50 tails. Sometimes you get 49 and 51, and on that rarest of occasions you can even get the same one 100 times.

With your above code you're not guaranteed to always get 20 zeroes and 80 ones when `noOfNodes` is 100. If you want to generate a vector that *always* has 20% zeroes, but with a random *ordering* of zeroes and ones, then you can accomplish this using the function [RANDPERM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randperm.html) like so:

```
operation = [zeros(1,20) ones(1,80)];  %# Fill the vector with 0 and 1
operation = operation(randperm(100));  %# Randomly reorder it
```

If you want to generate a vector that has anywhere from 0% to 20% zeroes, you can modify the code above using the function [RANDI](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randi.html):

```
operation = [randi([0 1],1,20) ones(1,80)];
operation = operation(randperm(100));
```

Comment: thank you. will this give always 20% or( 20% and less==> <=20%)?

Comment: @pac: Yes, it will always give you a vector with 20% zeroes. I updated my answer to show you how you can generate a vector with between 0% and 20% zeroes.

Comment: well I tried the following:                                operation= [randi([0 1],1,20) ones(1,80)];
operation= operation(randperm(noOfNodes));       I got the result: 1     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1 is this 80% or less? what is wrong?

Comment: @pac: Your `noOfNodes` is probably set to 20 instead of 100 (i.e. it should be the length of `operation`).

Comment: I want to generate noOfNodes (variable) times values of zeros and ones.only 20% of which will be zeros. should I add randi([0 1],1,(noOfNodes-noOfnodes*0.8) ones(1,noOfnodes*0.8)]; !

Comment: Yes I have tried it the above code is working thanks grovice you saved my life

Comment: there is one slight problem: noOfnodes*0.8 should be integer. is there a solution other than using round or something similar?

Comment: @pac: You'll have to round it off to an integer somehow, either by using function like [ROUND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/round.html), [FLOOR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/floor.html), [CEIL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ceil.html), or [FIX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fix.html), or by converting `noOfNodes` to an [integer type](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-52790.html) first (like `uint8(noOfNodes)*0.8`).